# Custom Skin: style popup

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm struggling again to style a popup, which gets created in a custom [skin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html).

I guess I have to use the [PopupControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html), not [Popup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html).

```
PopupControl popup = new PopupControl();
popup.getScene().setRoot(popupContentPane);
popup.setAutoHide(true);
popup.setAnchorLocation(PopupWindow.AnchorLocation.WINDOW_BOTTOM_LEFT);
popup.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
popup.getStyleClass().add("my-popup");
popup.show(getSkinnable(), screenLocation.getX(), screenLocation.getY());
```

The skinnable overrides the userAgentStylesheet:

```
@Override
public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
    return Stylesheets.getDefaultStylesheet();
}
```

But neither the style, nor the styleClass nor any styleClass applied to any child node of popupContentPane has some effect.

If I understand [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html#getStyleableParent--) correctly the popup should use the stylesheet of the ownerNode (here the skinnable).

The question is somewhat similar to an old question of mine, which didn't get any answer at that time: [Custom control & opaque popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610639/custom-control-opaque-popup)

How can I style the popup?

**Update**

Here a SSCCE which follows [~wzbergers] tip, though it looks strange for that a skin is needed for the popup as well. The styling still doesn't work:

MinimalApplication:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MinimalApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MinimalControl minimalControl = new MinimalControl();
        minimalControl.setText("test");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(minimalControl);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

MinimalControl:

```
package test;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import test.skin.MinimalControlSkin;
import test.skin.Stylesheets;


public class MinimalControl extends Control {

    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "minimal-control";

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "text");

    public MinimalControl() {
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
        return Stylesheets.getDefaultStylesheet();
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MinimalControlSkin(this);
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

MinimalControlSkin:

```
package test.skin;

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.PopupWindow;
import test.MinimalControl;

public class MinimalControlSkin extends SkinBase<MinimalControl> {

    private final Label label = new Label();
    private final BorderPane contentPane = new BorderPane(label);
    private final MinimalPopup popup = new MinimalPopup();

    public MinimalControlSkin(MinimalControl control) {
        super(control);
        getChildren().add(contentPane);

        label.textProperty().bind(control.textProperty());
        label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> openPopup());

        popup.setAutoHide(true);
        popup.setAnchorLocation(PopupWindow.AnchorLocation.WINDOW_BOTTOM_LEFT);
    }

    private void openPopup() {
        Bounds localBounds = label.getBoundsInLocal();
        Bounds screenBounds = label.localToScreen(localBounds);

        popup.show(label, screenBounds.getMinX(), screenBounds.getMinY());
    }

}
```

MinimalPopup:

```
package test.skin;

import javafx.scene.control.PopupControl;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class MinimalPopup extends PopupControl {

    private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "minimal-popup";

    public MinimalPopup() {
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MinimalPopupSkin(this);
    }

}
```

MinimalPopupContentPane:

```
package test.skin;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class MinimalPopupContentPane extends BorderPane {
    private final Label label = new Label("some popup text");

    public MinimalPopupContentPane() {
        setCenter(label);
    }


    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return label.textProperty();
    }

}
```

MinimalPopupSkin:

```
package test.skin;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class MinimalPopupSkin implements Skin<MinimalPopup> {

    private final MinimalPopup popup;
    private MinimalPopupContentPane contentPane = new MinimalPopupContentPane();

    public MinimalPopupSkin(MinimalPopup popup) {
        this.popup = popup;
        contentPane.idProperty().bind(popup.idProperty());
        contentPane.styleProperty().bind(popup.styleProperty());
        contentPane.getStyleClass().addAll(popup.getStyleClass());
    }

    @Override
    public MinimalPopup getSkinnable() {
        return popup;
    }

    @Override
    public Node getNode() {
        return contentPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        contentPane = null;
    }

}
```

Stylesheets:

package test.skin;

```
public class Stylesheets {

    private Stylesheets() {
    }

    public static String getDefaultStylesheet(){
        return Stylesheets.class.getResource("modena/modena.css").toExternalForm();
    }
}
```

test/skin/modena/modena.css:

```
.minimal-control { 
    -fx-skin: "test.skin.MinimalControlSkin";
}

.minimal-control .popup {
    -fx-border-color: black; /* -fx-box-border; */
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.minimal-control PopupControl {
    -fx-border-color: black; /* -fx-box-border; */
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.minimal-popup {
    -fx-border-color: black; /* -fx-box-border; */
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.minimal-control .minimal-popup {
    -fx-border-color: black; /* -fx-box-border; */
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PopupControl is not a Node - so you have to style it's content-pane or better provide a skin which binds the styles to the content-pane just like in the example below.

```
PopupControl popup = new PopupControl() {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
      return new PopupControlSkin(this, popupContentPane);
    }
};
...
  public class PopupControlSkin implements Skin<PopupControl> {

  private PopupControl popup;
  private Pane content;

  public PopupControlSkin(final PopupControl control, final Pane content) {
    this.popup = control;
    this.content = content;
    content.idProperty().bind(popup.idProperty());
    content.styleProperty().bind(popup.styleProperty());
    content.getStyleClass().addAll(popup.getStyleClass());
  }

  @Override 
  public Node getNode() {
      return content;
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose(){
  }

  @Override
  public PopupControl getSkinnable(){
    return popup;
  }
}
```

Comment: please see my SSCCE. IT follows this approach but the styling still has no effect.

Comment: You have to override #getUserAgentStylesheet of the popup content pane.
    public class MinimalPopupContentPane extends BorderPane {

        @Override
        public String getUserAgentStylesheet()
        {
          return Stylesheets.getDefaultStylesheet();
        }
    ....